# Running Android App in background or as a constant notification

Tags: java, android, service

I'm learning how to make apps for android and I have started by creating one which makes my phone scream when its dropped.

I got it working to where the phone screams when dropped, but now I need to make it so that the phone screams when dropped even when the app is closed, and to show a notification in the notification bar saying that its running

What should I use to do this? Should I use intentService? Ive been looking all over and I'm not sure where to look. Any guides would be appreciated

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your service run in the foreground. You can achieve this by showing a notification when your `service` is running.

This is how you need to make your service run as foreground

```
private void showNotification(String title)
{
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(title);

    startForeground(1000,mBuilder.build());  // 1000 - is Id for the notification
}
```

You can also set your custom `RemoteViews` in notification using `setContent`

You can remove the  service from foreground state using `stopForeground`

Answer (score -1):

check [Service Training](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

For your use case it's important that it's an foreground service:
[Documentation Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29)